# For a critical number, $(a,b)$ in 3-space, given that D = $f_{xx}$ $(a,b)*f_{yy}$ $(a,b)$ - $[f_{xy}$ $(a,b)]^2$, what do we do when $D = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

According to my lesson notes:

- If $D > 0$ and $f_{xy}$$(a,b) < 0$, then critical point $(a,b)$ is a relative maximum.
- If $D > 0$ and $f_{xy}$$(a,b) > 0$, then critical point $(a,b)$ is a relative minimum.
- If $D < 0$, then critical point $(a,b)$ is a saddle point.

How do we classify this critical point when $D = 0$? Everywhere I have looked has more or less said that these cases are rare and difficult, but I can't find a source that explains how one might find this.

Comment: The test is inconclusive then:  it tells you nothing.  You have to get it through other means.

Comment: Then how do we classify (a,b)? Can you link a source detailing "other means?"

Comment: Also, your notes should check the sign of $f_{xx}$ of $f_{yy}$ and not the mixed partials.

Comment: There is no other general technique (of which I'm aware) other than "playing with it" until you figure it out.  Sometimes you can examine the surface along different cuts to figure out what's going on.

Comment: inconclusive means that it could be maximum, minimum or saddle point. Depends on the specific function that is given to you.